# HKEY CURRENT USER - Key intermittently disappears

Tags: windows-registry

I have a TFS build that runs on a server and requires a registry key to be available. More details about this here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25054572/426422

My problem is that once in a while this key vanishes from HKCU without a trace.

To my knowledge there aren't any server restores or anything going on. The user account the key is under is a tfs service account and so no user is logging in and doing anything out of the ordinary either.

What could cause a registry key in HKCU to just intermittently disappear like this?

Answer (score 0):

You could run [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) on the server and filter on that specific registry key. When it's deleted it will show up with who did it and then you can investigate why

Comment: I don't think anyone is logging in as the service account and deleting anything. There are only two folks who know the password and one of them is me.

Comment: Running this will tell you who/what/when deleted it and then you can start you investigation of why

Comment: I understand about Process Monitor but I am asking if there are any common reasons aside from human intervention as to why a key could disappear. I've never heard of keys just vanishing.

Comment: you could have some configuration management software that is removing it, AV software, ect. You wont know until you perform the auditing with a tool